# Unable to Connect to Azure SQL Database - Error: 10061

Tags: string, azure, connection

I am encountering an issue while attempting to connect to  in Azure SQL Database.I get an error when trying to connect to MS sql management studio, azure data studio (im log in)and my .net application.
[image: Azure data studio]

[image: .net]

[image: sql managment]

"Cannot connect to lfconfig.database.windows.net. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10061)"

Steps taken:

-Verified the accuracy of the connection string.
-Confirmed that SQL Server allows remote connections.
-Checked the server's accessibility and ensured it is running.
-Reviewed firewall settings to ensure necessary ports are open.
-Tested the connection from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and successfully connected.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to connect to Azure SQL server, but I was unable to connect to it and I got the same error:

[image]

I am using my corporate network. I switched to another network, and I tried to connect again then the connection was successful.

Along with that check below option while connecting to the SQL server:

- Make sure outbound traffic over port 1433 will allowed by your network's firewall.
- Make sure you have given correct details of SQL server.

For more information you can refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection).